# I couldn't make a list with these codes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I couldn't make a list with these codes in python

```
  import os
path = r'C:\Users\fabri\Downloads\arquivos'
extension = '.csv'
for root, dirs_list, files_list in os.walk(path):
    for file_name in files_list:
        if os.path.splitext(file_name)[-1] == extension:
            file_name_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
            print(file_name_path)
```

Comment: You have not created any list. What's your question?

Comment: What kind of list are you trying to make? You're just printing filenames.

Comment: If you want a list of all the CSV files in the folder, `glob.glob()` would be a simpler way to do it.

Comment: I need to join all the csvs of a folder and its subfolders, the only way I managed to get all the names of all the files was with this code, but I can't make it a list to be able to concatenate them all @bereal

Comment: @Barmar  I need to join all the csvs of a folder and its subfolders, the only way I managed to get all the names of all the files was with this code, but I can't make it a list to be able to concatenate them all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `glob.glob()` with the `recursive=True` option to get all the matching files in a folder and its subfolders.

```
from glob import glob
path = r'C:\Users\fabri\Downloads\arquivos'
file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '**/*.csv'), recursive=True)
```

Comment: worked perfectly. Thank you very much